# finish all activities, start a new one as single instance

Tags: android

I want to finish all activities in my app and start a new single instance activity.
If someone attempts to start that same activity again, then it should stay as top and only `onNewIntent()` called. I don't want it to be recreated.
How can I do that?
I have tried a combination of different flags for launching but it didn't work.

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK, FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK,
FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

These flags didn't help to start the single instance activity.

Comment: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Works Fine Form me

Comment: @AbubakarRafi that recreates my activity. I don't want it to be recreated. Thanks though